# Erro query php/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para fazer uma query no banco de dados, só que está dando o seguinte erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Admin::$db
>   Filename: core/Model.php
>   Line Number: 51
>
> **Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/*****/public_html/application/models/admin_model.php on line 4**

### Código

```
class Admin_model extends CI_Model {
   public function carregar_hoteis(){
        $hoteis = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela");
        $array=array();
        foreach($hoteis->result() as $row)
        {
             $array['hoteis'][]=$row;
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
   }
}
```

Comment: Por acaso você esta carregando a library database? Só por desencargo...

Comment: Não deveria ser `$this->db->get` ao invés de `$this->db->query`?

Comment: @Ricardo o CodeIgniter permite as duas formas. Da uma olhada aqui: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na variável `$this->db`, que não é um objeto. Provavelmente essa variável recebe uma instância da conexão com a base de dados, a conexão não deve estar acontecendo e, por isso, o valor da variável é `null` (e não um objeto).

Sugestão: verifique se o framework está conectando com o banco de dados e se, na altura desse código, tentou-se fazer alguma conexão :)

Comment: é no meu controller eu não tinha dado o ultimo parâmetro para acessar o banco de dados como true.. por exemplo: `
$this->load->model('Admin_model', 'model_admin',true);`

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha boa! não se esqueça de dar um OK na resposta então, se você julgá-la correta :)

Answer (score 2):

Inicializaste a libraria Database no ficheiro application/config/autoload.php?

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```